# Souscrire (à) une assurance maladie : transitif ou intransitif ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, verbes

J'ai trouvé les deux options en ligne et les explications des dictionnaires que j'ai consulté n'ont pas résolu mes doutes. J'ai demandé à tous mes amis francophones et tout le monde a des réponses différentes. Est-il possible que les deux versions soient acceptés ?

Merci !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Le verbe souscrire, qu’on emploie notamment dans le domaine de
> l’assurance, signifie « donner à un acte une valeur d'engagement en le
> signant ». Dans ce sens, il s'agit d'un emploi transitif direct; le
> verbe n’est donc pas suivi d’une préposition.
>
> Exemples :
>
> - L’été dernier, Marie a souscrit une assurance vie.
> - Accepteriez-vous de souscrire un abonnement à notre magazine?
>
> L'emploi transitif indirect est également possible; le verbe est alors
> suivi de la préposition à. Souscrire à signifie généralement « donner
> son accord, son adhésion, consentir à quelque chose ».
>
> Exemples :
>
> - Le conseil municipal souscrit au projet d’agrandissement du parc.
> - Je souscris parfaitement à ce que vous dites.

Source: http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3657

EDIT: J'aurais du le préciser dès le début, mais il est assez courant aujourd'hui de voir l'emploi intransitif utilisé peu importe le contexte. A mon sens cela reste une erreur, mais je pense que beaucoup de gens laissent passer sans s'en rendre compte ou même se poser la question. Qui sait, peut-être l'emploi transitif va-t-il disparaître à terme dans une optique de simplification?

Comment: C'est effectivement l'usage prescriptif... mais force est de constater nombre de professionels s'alignent sur l'emploi transitif indirect: https://reassurez-moi.fr/guide/pro/garantie-decennale/maf#comment_souscrire_a_lrsquoassurance_decennale_batiment_maf

Comment: Effectivement; j'aurais sans doute du le préciser, je vais le faire de ce pas...